# Duplicity does not work

Tags: backup, restore

```
rod@rod:~$ duplicity list-current-files "file://871 GB Volume" > backup.list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1532, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1526, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1380, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1461, in do_backup
    list_current(col_stats)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 696, in list_current
    sig_chain = col_stats.get_signature_chain_at_time(time)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 994, in get_signature_chain_at_time
    raise CollectionsError("No signature chains found")
CollectionsError: No signature chains found
```

Comment: Seems like a bug already reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/1086374).

Comment: This error message is what duplicity (cryptically) says as a "file not found" error. I would not be surprised if the bug report is more related to "pls open backup" hysteria, common while being faced by a forced restore.

Answer (score 5):

You need three slashes after the colon, a la `file:///path/to/stuff`

Answer (score 0):

Had this behaviour (CollectionsError: No signature chains found)
when temp dir wasn't big enough to store expanded signature files.

The solution was to set the temp dir in the command-line to a location having enough space.

```
duplicity --tempdir /enough/space/tmp list-current-files file:///backupdir/
```